# Create multiple records in a table from textarea

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-4

From one of my views I get a string of words which are sent from a textarea and every new row is a new record in the db.

Because I do many checks, and probably my code is not designed so well, I get timeouts.
This process includes actions like, splitting the rows, downcaseing the words, removing white spaces, assigning sidekiqs workers and checking if there is any historical data about that word in another table, also there is a validation of uniqueness.

How can I improve this process, is queuing a solution?

Thank you.

Comment: You mentioned Sidekiq, so it seems you're already using a queue. Right?

Comment: Yes, but I am using the queue for other processes, not for inserting words in a database.

Answer (score 0):

put the long running task in a queue is better, try the delayed_job gem here https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job